# How to debug when a dependency fails to instantiate?

Tags: c#, debugging, dependency-injection, unity-container

How do you debug dependency injection (using Unity DI) when the dependancy does not instantiate?

eg Given a service class with dependencies:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    [Dependency]
    public BarService BarService { get; set; }
    [Dependency]
    public AnotherService AnotherService { get; set; }

    // other code fails because BarService and AnotherService are null
}
```

And in Global.asax.cs

```
private void ConfigureIoC()
{
    container
        .ConfigureAutoRegistration()
        .LoadAssembliesFrom(assemblyPaths)
        .ExcludeSystemAssemblies()
        .Include(If.Any, Then.Register()) 
        .ApplyAutoRegistration();

    var serviceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
}
```

The IFooService is also instantiated by Unity, but that uses constructor injection instead (and it works):

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IFooService _fooService;
    public FooController(IFooService fooService)
    {
        _fooService = fooService;
    }
}
```

How can I debug this to see why the dependencies are failing to instantiate.  No exceptions are being thrown (or if they are then Elmah is not catching and logging them).

Comment: Please avoid including things like _C#, Debugging, Unity, dependency injection_in your question titles. That is what the tags are for.

Comment: What I usually do in cases like this is linking my code unit with the *source* project of Unity, and then I step through the Unity code, to see how stuff is being resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency is not injected because the `DependencyAttribute` is on the concrete class instead of the interface.

As DI attributes [can be harmful](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/27/WhatsSoDangerousAboutADIAttribute.aspx) I would recommend you change the registration to

```
container.RegisterType<IFooService,FooService>(new InjectionProperty("BarService"), new InjectionProperty("AnotherService"));
```

Resolving `IFooService` will then return an instance of `FooService` with the injected dependencies.

Comment: An even better advice would be to use constructor injection instead of property injection.

Comment: @Steven Depending on wether these dependencies are "must have" (constructor injection) or "nice to have" (property injection) dependencies you are absolutely right.

Comment: I must say I'm a bit dazzled that Unity doesn't fail when a property that is explicitly decorated with the [Dependency] attribute can't be injected. Failing silently makes the configuration much more fragile.

Comment: @Steven It is not failing, it is exactly doing what you ask for. "Give me an IFooService". And so it does. If you ask for a `FooService` it will fill the properties. But the interface does not tell Unity to inject anything.

Comment: No, Unity will fill in the properties that are explicitly decorated, but *only* if those types are registered. Otherwise it will silently skip them, which is IMO not what you want most of the time, because this means that you can't easily verify the correctness of the DI configuration.

Comment: Yes it is failing silently, which doesn't help at all.  I will switch to constructor injection and see if that helps.  Everything else in the solution uses constructor injection, so I'm not sure why this one doesn't too.

Comment: I tried various combinations on how to register or not register the properties and their respective service classes with the container and could not find a way where it fails silently. I don't know the internals of the Unity Auto Registration project that well to say what it does but if I register the mapping from `IFooService` to `FooService` manually it works. It even honors the `DependencyAttribute` on the concrete class.

Comment: @Steven It will also fill the properties if the type `FooService` is not explicitely registered. Just validated that. But in order to resolve the interface `IFooService` the implementation type has to be registered anyway.

Comment: But the creation of `FooService` will succeed, even if `BarService` is not registered (or can not be created), which is what makes this type of configuration fragile. That's why constructor injection should be used if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Call `container.Resolve<IFooService>();`

Where/how is resolution of IFooService happening?

Comment: I updated the question to show how FooService is instantiated, and that part works.

Comment: Someone who knows more about Unity and setter injection may have to answer (I haven't used it in a while), but I would try temporarily making the dependencies all constructor-injected, just to see if they resolve.  If they don't, the error should tell you why.  If they do, then it must be how you have the setter injection set up.